# cakephp: where to place Configure::write in app_controller?

Tags: cakephp, variables, global, declaration

after reading 'What is the best way to create global variables in CakePHP?' in stackoverflow, I tried to configure my school's email id as follows:

```
Configure::write('School.email','support@merryflowers.com')
```

but I don't know on where to place the above code in app_controller so that it is accessible to all models, views and controllers. Can someone help me?

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placing such constants in *bootstrap.php* or *core.php* is [advised](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/954/Bootstrapping-CakePHP). Both of these files are located in `app/config/`.

I personally think *bootstrap.php* is cleaner.

Comment: yes, i placed it in bootstrap.php and it worked. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's a global setting required everywhere that never changes, put it in `app/config/core.php`.